# Re-writing a line using python + curses

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

When I try to print, for example:

```
Queue  Messages    Size
----------
Postfix  10          1024
```

I need to re-print this line with another values, so if the value is 0, for example, the result is:

```
Postfix  00          0024
```

I need to fix it to:

```
Postfix  0           0
```

I can do that using `window.clrtoeol()`, but it erases my right border.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this hasn't gotten any answers yet, but anyways

I assume that you are keeping good track of your column locations, widths, and boundaries. If you are the answer is simple: pad your number with spaces, so the '024' bit is overwritten with blank spaces.

I feel its good practice to use addstr like so

```
window.addstr( y , x , message[:width].ljust(width) , mode )
```